# SVG inline icon collection

Tags: css, svg, icons, inline

I have a footer with a collection of icons.
I can't use one big picture with all icons in it due to responsive reasons.

My solution was to insert the icons as svg inline code.
But now i have 5000 code lines more. Is that ok? I think it could be a issue with SEO but definitly better more performant then load every image separatly.

How would you solve this?

Thank you.

[The collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aj0k.png)

Comment: Read up on [SVG Sprite Creation Techniques](https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/).

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Great. Thank you.